# a array of week days[mon,wed,thu,fri,sun] display in string like mon,wed-fri,sun

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

A array of week days `[Mon,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sun]` and display it in string like `Mon,Wed-Fri,sun` using TS or JS.

Where the continues day will be like Wed-Fri.

```
ex-1  [Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,sat,sun] display like Mon-Sun
ex-2  [Mon,Tue,Thu,Fri,Sat,sun] display like Mon-Tue,Thu-sun
ex-2  [Mon,Tue,Thu,Sat,Sun] display like Mon-Tue,Thu,sat-sun
```

Comment: Ask a detailed question with what you want, what have you tried and whats the problem. Dont be shy to show us some code. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Using a library is always better than trying to handle these needs manually. Please take a look at this https://blog.logrocket.com/javascript-date-libraries/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const fullList = ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun']
function optimizeList(list) {
  var from = -1, to = -1, res = [];
  fullList.forEach(function(n, idx) {
    var found = list.indexOf(n) >= 0;
    if (found && to >= 0 && idx === to + 1)
      to = idx;
    if (from === -1 && found)
      from = to = idx;
    if (to >= 0 && (idx === fullList.length - 1 || to !== idx)) {
      res.push(fullList[from] + (to !== from ? '-' + fullList[to] : ''));
      from = to = -1;
    }
  })
  return res
}

console.log(optimizeList(['Mon','Tue','Fri','Sun']))
console.log(optimizeList(['Tue','Fri']))
console.log(optimizeList(['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun']))
console.log(optimizeList(['Sat','Sun']))
console.log(optimizeList(['Tue','Wed']))
```

Comment: Thanks bro ,it works for me but i want result in string not in array........but now i will figure it out ..........thanks again